# Change origin of plot in Julia

Tags: plot, julia, axis

Imagine the following simple plot with `Plots`

```
using Plots
plot([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5])
```

Output:

[image]

How can we change the origin to 0 in the plot above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually very simple, you can use the arguments `xlims` and `ylims` and pass `0` and `Inf` as the limits to force the axis to an origin of 0. Here is a reproducible example:

```
using Plots
plot([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5], xlims = [0,Inf], ylims = [0,Inf])
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see the origin has been changed!

Comment: TBH, Julia's default plotting settings are much inferior to, e.g., MATLAB's. See [this output](https://imgur.com/OEKiDsK) from the same `plot([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5])` in MATLAB. Even Python's [matplotlib's output](https://imgur.com/hwdh7c5) looks better.